# Can't uninstall app installed using diawi

Tags: applications, iphone, ios

I installed an app on iPhone 6 running iOS 11 using diawi.com.

For some reason I can't open it, nothing happens when I click the icon, and I also can't uninstall the app.
There is nothing on the profiles settings.

What can I do to remove the app from the device?

Comment: Have you tried to delete that app with iTunes? [How-to-delete-an-uploaded-app](https://www.diawi.com/knowledge-base/Diawi/How-to-delete-an-uploaded-app)

Comment: Maybe the people of Diawi.com have a better answer for you.

Comment: @AndreyKuznetsov It's not my iPhone, so I can't bring it home for my Mac...

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete it with iTunes on your computer or if you have an old backup, where the app wasn't on your phone, try to overwrite the actual phone version with the old backup. Another possibility would be to save all your important data and reset your phone and then import all the data back on the phone.

Comment: It's not my iPhone, so I most of the chances that I won't be able to bring to my Mac at home, and resetting is not an option for this case. What else can I do?